# Why is my page not scrollable?

Tags: html, css, scrollable

So I have made a few pages that use the following css code:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
    ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 00px;
    left: 00px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 700px; 

    background-image:url('/images/B_left-background.png');
}

ul.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
    left: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    width:700px;
    background-image:url('/images/B_left-top.png');
}

body {

    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;

    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;

    background-color: #D6E9B4;
}
div.scrollableContainer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 ;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
h1 {font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,
        SunSans-Regular, sans-serif }
ul.navbar a {text-decoration: none }

a.send{
    color: black;
    background-image:url('/images/send-message-bt.png');
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    left:0px;
    height:80px;
    width:290px;
}

a.token{
    color: black;
    background-image:url('/images/token-ID-bt.png');
    position:fixed;
    top:300px;
    left:0px;
    height:80px;
    width:290px;
}

a.history{
    color: black;
    background-image:url('/images/history-bt.png');
    position:fixed;
    top:400px;
    left:0px;
    height:80px;
    width:290px;
}

a.comp{
    background-image:url('/images/competition-bt.png');
    position:fixed;
    top:500px;
    left:0px;
    height:80px;
    width:290px;
}

a.out{
    background-image:url('/images/B_log-out-bt.png');
    position:fixed;
    top:600px;
    left:50px;
    height:60px;
    width:160px;
}
```

I would like to make the whole page scrollable, so that if someone on a low-resolution device can still scroll down. 
As you can see I put in the:
    html { overflow-y: scroll; }
But this does not help.

Is there any way I can fix this? Does it have something to do with me setting the fixed-heights?

Comment: it's all your fixed positioning that's causing the problem, that page does not know how long it is hence why you never get a scrollbar, try to change it to relative or absolute and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @Reina: absolute is no better than fixed in this situation, since both take the elements out of the normal flow of the document.

Comment: thanks reina, i think you might be right. any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
body { position: absolute; }
```

Or this:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden; }
body { position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 6):

overflow-y: scroll;
to both body and html

```
html,body{overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was an:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

in the css of the first child of the body with was preventing the page from becoming scrollable. Once I removed it the page could scroll.